# Return global array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, global

I am trying to simply print out a global array list of students that I have imported from a csv file. I've done enough troubleshooting to know that the data is being imported and read fine. The common answer seems to be that you don't require a "var" declaration for a global array but this wasn't working for me either.

Here is my declaration:

```
//Student array list from csv import
 studentList = []; 
//window.studentList = [];
```

This is where I initialize the array:

```
function processData(csv){
let allLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/); 

for(let i = 0; i < allLines.length; i++)
{
    let row = allLines[i].split(",");
    let col = []; 

    for(let j = 0; j < row.length; j++)
    {
       col.push(row[j]);  
    }
    if(col == " ") break;
    studentList.push(col);
}

//when I alert the array element by element the data is being read from within this function 
for(let i =0; i < studentList.length; i++)
{
    alert(studentList[i]);
}
}
```

But if I was to use a get method to return the elements I would get an 'undefined' error

```
function getStudent(index) {
     return studentList[index];
}

for(let i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++)
{
      alert(getStudent[i]);
}
```

**EDIT:** Despite that solution being right, I still have the same issue when calling from another function. For example in the following I need to return the trip departure for each student which is undefined.

```
function getStudentsDeparture(i)  
{
    trip.departure = getStudent(i);
    alert(trip.departure);          //prints undefined

    trip.destination = "123 Smith Rd, Maddingley VIC 3340"; 
    console.log('dest is: ' + trip.destination + ' dept is: ' + 
    trip.departure);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be that you try to get an index from the function `getStudent[i]`. Try change that row to `alert(getStudent(i));` with parenthesis.

**EDIT**
I tested with this code and it works fine for me

```
studentList = [];

studentList.push('student1');

function getStudent(index) {
    return studentList[index];
}

function getStudentsDeparture(i) {
    var student = getStudent(i);
    alert(student);
}

getStudentsDeparture(0);
```

Comment: You are right, but when still when I try from a separate function I am still getting undefined.

Comment: @Stefan Are you sure that the index is within range of `studentList` array?